# Size comparison in R(data-visualization)

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am building a size comparison script. I will enter a data.frame where I will have a list of all the objects that I want to compare(different kinds of molecules).

And I was wondering are there any good ways for me to be able to import custom images for every object I enter into the data frame, so I could better visualize the data, since I am building this for youngsters who will not really understand the plots of data.

Comment: It's not quite clear what sort of images you are thinking of.  Are these images that exist on your hard drive – in which case you could include a file name as a column of your data.frame – or could R generate the images for you itself instead of plots?

Comment: I tried puting a file in data.frame column, but that way I can only display one by one file(.png). And the point of this script is to show all the objects side to side, so you could see the size difference between them.

Comment: If you are looking to display multiple images at once, perhaps this post will help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668102/plotting-several-jpeg-images-in-a-single-display

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I was looking for!